# .NET Generic List(Of FileInfo) search using FileInfo.FullName

Tags: .net, list, dictionary

Example: I have a lot of FileInfo objects inside a List. Potentially 10000s. I need to check if the list contains a given FileInfo object using its FullName property. I am not even interested in an index, I just want to know if it is there. The naive approach would be For...Next, however there should be a faster way.

So this is what this question is about in general:

```
Class Foo
   Friend SomeString as String
   Friend SomeInteger as Integer
End Class

Module Work
    Dim FooList as New List(Of Foo)

    Friend Function IsInList(aString as String) as Boolean
       'The question is what to do here other than the below:
       For i = 0 to FooList.Count - 1
           If (FooList(i).SomeString = aString) Then Return True
       Next
       Return False
    End Function
End Module
```

What are the approaches for the above? I mean I could use a separate Dictionary(Of String, Integer) that would map SomeString key in Foo to Index of a particular Foo in FooList, but that is rather ugly.

Perhaps there is a lightweight Dictionary/List combo class?

Ideally I would like to write something like this:

```
FooList.IndexOf(SomeStringValue)
```

Even though the actual list is a List of Foo, not a List of String.

EDIT: Ideally, .NET 2.0 solution would be proffered.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there is such collection. It's `HashSet<T>` and you just have to implement your own `IEquatable<FileInfo>` to compare (and get hash code) for the `FileInfo.FullName` property. Internally it's implemented using an hashtable so a search for a specific element will be much faster. Same thing can be done using a `Dictionary<String, FileInfo>` too (where key is `FileInfo.FullName`) (of course search will be little bit slower because you'll compare strings instead of integers but you won't need to worry about collisions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I need something where order is important, and which is available in .NET 2.0, So HashSet is not really an option.

Comment: If you can't use HashSet you still can use Dictionary, in your case a SortedDictionary (if order matters). If order matters and it's somehow applicable to FullName then I'd also try to perform a binary search (to compare performance with a SortedDictionary, especially for adding new elements).

Comment: Tens of thousands is still quite well within the realm of linear search, provided that you're not doing the search in a cycle. Especially if the comparison ends up being fast, e.g. the difference between the two strings appears ASAP - different length, different first few characters (that one's not going to work well for full name). Also, don't be too affraid of `Dictionary<string, FileInfo>` or `Dictionary<string, bool>` alongside the `List<FileInfo>`. It's a common pattern. Now, if the data is ordered on input (as in, sorted by the file name), you can use e.g. a binary search.